# prettyphoto wont load when writing href using document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

i have some codes like this

```
<span id="$RsC" class="menu" title="Action menu" onclick="menu(\''.$RsC.'\')">click</span>

function menu(id){ 
var d = document.getElementById(id); 
d.innerHTML ='<a href="somthing;iframe=true&amp;width=400&amp;height=170"  rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]" >Doesnt work</a>';
}

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".pp_pic_holder").remove();
 $(".pp_overlay").remove();
 $(".ppt").remove();
$(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'h0mayun'});
});
</script>
```

the problem is that after clicking on *"click"* and writing html link prettyPhoto plugin doesn't load

any help will be appreciated.

EDIT-------------------
damn you conflict it was again jquery conflict but to got it work i change function to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".pp_pic_holder").remove();
 $(".pp_overlay").remove();
 $(".ppt").remove();
$(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'h0mayun'});
});
</script>

function menu(id){ 
var d = document.getElementById(id); 
d.innerHTML ='<a href="somthing;iframe=true&amp;width=400&amp;height=170"  rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]" >Doesnt work</a>';
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".pp_pic_holder").remove();
 $(".pp_overlay").remove();
 $(".ppt").remove();
$(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'h0mayun'});
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And it is not going to work this way. You initialize prettyPhoto for existing elements on the page after your page was loaded. When you insert a new element, prettyPhoto plugin knows nothing about it, because it already "attached" itself to the elements existed before. You have to initialize prettyPhoto after all changes on the page or attach it after changes to the updated elements. Like this

```
function menu(id){ 
var d = document.getElementById(id); 
d.innerHTML ='<a href="somthing;iframe=true&amp;width=400&amp;height=170"  rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]" >Doesnt work</a>';
$('a', d).prettyPhoto({theme:'h0mayun'});
}
```

ps: I've made a simple test with the example of prettyPhoto and it is working

```
function menu(id){ 
var d = document.getElementById(id); 
d.innerHTML ='<a href="images/fullscreen/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]">Test link</a>';
$('a', d).prettyPhoto();
}
```

Comment: @h0mayun       do you have a link to the page to view it in action?

Comment: @h0mayun       replace the part of my code with $('a', d).click(function(){alert("I'm here!"); return false;}); and try it (click on the link "Doesnt work"). Do you see alert message? I don't use prettyPhoto, that is why I asked you about the link.

Comment: @h0mayun       And I've made a test (cited in the answer) with an example of the prettyPhoto - it is working, so there must be something else that creates a problem on your page. For example - link to the image is incorrect or not recognized by the prettyPhoto script.

Comment: it doesn't work either :(
the whole function is something like that:

function menu( e, id ,spanid,dirFile,href,dirName,file) {

var d = document.getElementById(id); 
d.innerHTML = ' <a href="'+href+'" target="iframe" > /
<a href="'+href+'"  ><span title="open in new tab">new tab</a> /
';
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = ( el.style.display == 'block' ) ? 'none' : 'block';

  menu.el = el;
$('a', d).prettyPhoto();

  // stop the event right here
  if ( e.stopPropagation )
    e.stopPropagation();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  return false;

}

Comment: and im sure that links are fine

Comment: @h0mayun       upload it to any filesharing service. you have a few "a" tags in your replacement. The href variable - is that a path to the image?

Comment: i added whole
`code`
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".pp_pic_holder").remove();
 $(".pp_overlay").remove();
 $(".ppt").remove();
$(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'h0mayun'});
}); 
`code`
below
d.innerHTML
and now it works in my test page but not in my main page
but i think im close
i will figure it out
thanks anyway

Comment: +1. This answer should have been accepted. Excellent write-up, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this `$(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'h0mayun'});` before the onClick function.

You would have to do it again after you have written the html of the object so the plugin would initialize again.