# Smart Loading Images in a Slideshow + Lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, cycle, prettyphoto, photoswipe

I was looking for a responsive slideshow plugin that allow me to do a progressive images loading, and I found [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/progressive.php). This seems to use something like innerHTML to add images inside the slideshow and it´s that because either `prettyPhoto` or `PhotoSwipe` don't work with added images. Here is a similar problem: [prettyphoto wont load when writing href using document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010089/prettyphoto-wont-load-when-writing-href-using-document-write)

Somebody knows about similars plugins or how can add new images to lightbox index?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of test with no solution, I looked for another pluging and I´ve moved for [Camera slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) that loads the slideshow images on demand widhout appends it.

Finally the problem is solve :)